# Указатель на абстрактный класс. Проблема инициализации массивом

Tags: c++, наследование

### abstract_class_word.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class word {
protected:
    string language;
    string native_inscription;
    string translation;

public:
    word(const string &lang, const string &nat_inscr, const string &transl);

    virtual int show() = 0;
    virtual int save_to_disk() = 0;
    virtual int read_from_disk() = 0;
};


inline word::word(const string &lang, const string & nat_inscr, const string & transl) {
    language = lang;
    native_inscription = nat_inscr;
    translation = transl;
}
```

### english_word.h

```
#pragma once
#include "abstract_class_word.h"
using namespace std;

class english_word : public word {
    string example_sentence;
    static int number;
    int id;

public:
    english_word() = delete;
    english_word(const string &nat_inscr, const string &transl, const string &ex_sentence);

    virtual int show() override;
    virtual int save_to_disk() override;
    virtual int read_from_disk() override;
};


inline english_word::english_word(const string &nat_inscr, const string &transl, const string &ex_sentence) : word(string("EN"), nat_inscr, transl) {
    example_sentence = ex_sentence;
    id = ++number;
}

inline int english_word::show() {
    cout << id << "\t" << native_inscription << "\t->\t" << translation << endl;
    cout << "\t" << example_sentence << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
inline int english_word::save_to_disk() {
    return 0;
}
inline int english_word::read_from_disk() {
    return 0;
}

int english_word::number = 0;
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "headers\class_english_word.h"
#include <locale>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");

    word *wrd;
    wrd = new english_word[3] { english_word("cut","рубить","Cut down those trees."),
                                english_word("run","бежать","Run, Forrest, run!"),
                                english_word("sow","сеять","You earn what you sew.") };
    english_word *ewrd;
    ewrd = new english_word[3] { english_word("cut","рубить","Cut down those trees."),
                                english_word("run","бежать","Run, Forrest, run!"),
                                english_word("sow","сеять","You earn what you sew.") };

    for(auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        ewrd[i].show();

    for(auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        wrd[i].show(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<< exception!

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

### Проблема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатель `wrd` может указывать либо на один объект класса `word`, либо на массив класса `word`, либо на один объект класса `english_word`, но не на массив объектов класса `english_word`. Это происходит потому, что при индексировании адрес следующего элемента будет вычисляться как сумма базового адреса и произведения размера статического типа объекта на их количество.

```
wrd[i] -> wrd + sizeof(word) * i
```

В то время как в массиве `english_word[3]` адрес элемента должен быть `wrd + sizeof(english_word) * i`, при том что `sizeof(english_word)` больше, чем `sizeof(word)`. Соответственно вы получаете чтение по неправильному смещению.

Исправить можно добавлением одного уровня перенаправления:

```
::std::vector<::std::unique_ptr<word>> eng_words
{
    ::std::make_unique<english_word>("cut","рубить","Cut down those trees."),...
};

for(auto & p_word: eng_words)
{
    p_word->show();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, sizeof(wrd) намного меньше sizeof(english_word). Не правильно смещение указателя. А что Вы посоветуете если нужен массив english_word? Использовать массив указателей на word вместо этого и каждому записывать по одному english_word?